# Long Polling loop de request em phpt?

Tags: php, javascript, longpolling

Preciso criar uma forma de notificar os usuários do sistema cada vez que uma tabela do banco de dados recebe um novo registro.

Estou usando como base um exemplo publicado aqui [Server Push: Long Polling](http://rberaldo.com.br/server-push-long-polling-php-ios/) porém estou com alguns problemas, o primeiro deles é que analisando o network do navegador ele faz diversas solicitações até o navegador travar... e como consequência ele fica repetindo a lista de registro do banco de dados, segue o código do server.php:

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
include ('database.php');

$requestedTimestamp  = isset ( $_GET [ 'entry' ] ) ? (int)$_GET [ 'entry' ] : time();

while ( true )
{   
    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE entry >= :requestedTimestamp" );

    $stmt->bindParam(':requestedTimestamp', $requestedTimestamp);
    $stmt->execute();

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ( count( $rows ) > 0 ){          
        $json = json_encode( $rows );       
        echo $json;     
        break;
    }else{
        sleep( 2 );
        continue;
    }

}
```

e esse é o js:

```
function getContent( entry )
{
    var queryString = { 'entry' : entry };
    $.get('./database/server.php', queryString, function( data ) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data ),
        string = "";

        // lista obj json
        for (var i in obj) 
        {                  
            var classy = obj[i]['readable'] == 0 ? 'new-notfication' : '';
            string += '<div class="table notification-table '+classy+'">';
            string += '<div class="td"><img src="img/default/default-user-image.png" alt=""></div>';
            string += '<div class="td">';
            string += '<p><a href="#"><strong>'+obj[i]['title']+'</strong></a></p>';
            string += '<p>'+obj[i]['msg'].substr(0,66)+'...</p>';
            string += '</div>';
            string += '<div class="td"><a href="#" class="close"><span class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></div>';
            string += '</div>';
            $('#entry').append(string);
        }

        //reconecta
        //  getContent(data);
    });
}

getContent();
```

na primeira execução da função ele repete os registro e traz 6 valores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Procurei mais a respeito do long polling para entender como funciona e desenvolver a lógica: **server.php**

```
# includes de conexão
include ('config.php');
include ('database.php');
include ('conection.php');

# define momento em que começou a roda o Polling
$start = time();
# Defini tempo maximo da conexão
$timeRequest = 55;

#verifica se ouve post
if (isset( $_POST['entry'] )) {
    # previne injections e tags invalidas
    $entry = DBEscape( trim( $_POST['entry']  ) );
}else{
    # pega hora atual do servidor 
    $getTime = $PDO->prepare("SELECT NOW() as now");
    # executa query 
    $getTime->execute();
    # transforma o resultado em objeto
    $result = $getTime->fetchObject();
    # atribui valor do resultado
    $entry = $result->now;
}

# pepara a query para buscar os registro novos
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE entry > '$entry'" );

# controle para saber se ouve novo registro
$newData = false;
# array para as novas notificações
$notify = array();

# mantem a conexão aberta até o limite maximo estabelecido em $start
while (!$newData and (time()-$start) < $timeRequest ) {
    $stmt->execute();

# caso encontre resultado fecha a conexão
while ($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    # atribui valor do resultado
    $notify = $result;
    # encerra a conexão
    $newData = true;
}
# aguarda 1/2 segundo para abrir a conexão
usleep(500000);
}
# pega novamente a hora do servidor
$getTime = $PDO->prepare("SELECT NOW() as now");
# executa query
$getTime->execute();
# transforma resultado em objeto
$result = $getTime->fetchObject();
# atribui valor do resultado
$entry = $result->now;
# converte tudo em um array
$data = array('notify' => $notify, 'entry' => $entry );
# envia dados em formato Json para o front-end 
echo json_encode($data);
# encerra execução de escript php
exit;
```

**front-end**:

```
// chamada a função
getNotifications();

function getNotifications( entry )
{   
    // cria array de dados
    var data = {};
    // verifica se existe um tempo definido
    if(typeof entry != 'undefined'){
        // atribui o tempo definido ao objeto
        data.entry = entry;
    }

    // envia os dados para o script de polling
    $.post('./database/server.php', data, function(result) {           
        for(i in result.notify){
            // passa os valores para a lista de notitficações
            $('#entry').append(result.notify[i].title);
        }
        // reinicia a busca por dados
        getNotifications(result.entry);
    }, 'json');
}
```